# Json foreach loop is outputting the word object instead of its contents

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I am attempting to send the `foreach` loop through json and then display with `innerHTML`. There aren't any errors. The issue I am having is that the output is display:

> [object Object]

Instead of what is in the foreach loop.

How do I get the output to be the `$html` lines that are within the `foreach` loop?

```
try {
    $sql_recentProjects = "
        SELECT *
        FROM project_gallery
        ORDER BY date_added ASC
        LIMIT 5
    ";
    if ($recentProjects_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_recentProjects)) {
        $recentProjects_stmt->execute();
        $recentProjects_rows = $recentProjects_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $recProj_arr = array();
        foreach ($recentProjects_rows as $recentProjects_row) {
            $precProjName = $recentProjects_row['p_name'];
            $recProjImg = $recentProjects_row['p_img'];
            //$project_img = substr($project_img, 2);
            $displayRecProjImg = '<img src="/php'.$recProjImg.'" alt="'. $precProjAlt .'" class="projectDisplayImg">';
            $html = '';
            $html .= '<div class="recentProjectCont">';
            $html .= '<div class="recentProjectImg">';
            $html .= $displayRecProjImg;
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="recProjInfoCont">';
            $html .= '<div class="">';
            $html .= $precProjName;
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $recentProjData = array('html' => $html);
            //$proj_arr[] = $data;
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode(['recentProjectData' => $recentProjData]);
```

JS

```
function ajaxCallCatalogs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/projects/projectGallerySelect.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            recentProjectData = obj.recentProjectData; //Recent 5 Projects submitted to gallery

            document.getElementById('recentProjectWrap').innerHTML = recentProjectData;
        }
    });
}
ajaxCallCatalogs();
setInterval(ajaxCallCatalogs, 150000);
```

Comment: It's because you have `$recentProjData = array('html' => $html)`.  So `recentProjectData` is an object with an `html` element

Comment: Why aren't you just sending the  html string instead of trying to send as json?

Comment: If you get rid of the comment, look at how the data you're receiving is structured: //console.log(data);

Comment: Sorry everyone - I forgot to include the json encode line: `echo json_encode(['recentProjectData' => $recentProjData]);`

Comment: @Paul  I think we had pretty much assumed that existed somewhere.  It doesn't change anything that's already been stated.

Comment: @MarkOverton This is how the data is showing in the console (after uncommenting): `"recentProjectData":{"html":"<div class=\"recentProjectCont\"><div class=\"recentProjectImg\"><img src=\"/php..\/project_images\/mh5.jpg\" alt=\"Small transportation cart\" class=\"projectDisplayImg\"><\/div><div class=\"recProjInfoCont\"><div class=\"\">Small cart<\/div><\/div><\/div>"}`

Comment: @PatrickQ How would I change it to get the results to populate?

Comment: `document.getElementById('recentProjectWrap').innerHTML = recentProjectData.html;` or `document.getElementById('recentProjectWrap').innerHTML = recentProjectData['html'];`

Comment: @DanielC Thanks. That got the data to output. However, my the looped results aren't showing. I should have five results outputting. Only one is showing.

Comment: That's a problem with your foreach loop.  You re-initialize $html to nothing again, so you'll only ever get the LAST record.  `$html = '';` And then you overwrite your "array" with that last record... `$recentProjData = array('html' => $html);`

Comment: @DanielC Gotcha. Suggestions on what to change?

Comment: Posted it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Read the comments of the OP to know why I posted this answer)

You have two options...  the easiest way, but more restrictive method is this:

```
try {
    $sql_recentProjects = "
        SELECT *
        FROM project_gallery
        ORDER BY date_added ASC
        LIMIT 5
    ";
    if ($recentProjects_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_recentProjects)) {
        $recentProjects_stmt->execute();
        $recentProjects_rows = $recentProjects_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $recProj_arr = array();
        $html = '';  // MOVE THIS OUTSIDE THE LOOP
        foreach ($recentProjects_rows as $recentProjects_row) {
            $precProjName = $recentProjects_row['p_name'];
            $recProjImg = $recentProjects_row['p_img'];
            //$project_img = substr($project_img, 2);
            $displayRecProjImg = '<img src="/php'.$recProjImg.'" alt="'. $precProjAlt .'" class="projectDisplayImg">';
            $html .= '<div class="recentProjectCont">';
            $html .= '<div class="recentProjectImg">';
            $html .= $displayRecProjImg;
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="recProjInfoCont">';
            $html .= '<div class="">';
            $html .= $precProjName;
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            //$proj_arr[] = $data;
        }
        // SET THIS AFTER YOU GET ALL ROWS INTO THE STRING
        $recentProjData = array('html' => $html);
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode(['recentProjectData' => $recentProjData]);
```

Or, you can do this, which will truly separate the rows into more consumable data, but means you need to re-code your JS to output it proper (loop through the data via JS):

```
try {
    $sql_recentProjects = "
        SELECT *
        FROM project_gallery
        ORDER BY date_added ASC
        LIMIT 5
    ";
    if ($recentProjects_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_recentProjects)) {
        $recentProjects_stmt->execute();
        $recentProjects_rows = $recentProjects_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $recProj_arr = array( 'html' => array() );  // SET UP THE ARRAY
        foreach ($recentProjects_rows as $recentProjects_row) {
            $precProjName = $recentProjects_row['p_name'];
            $recProjImg = $recentProjects_row['p_img'];
            //$project_img = substr($project_img, 2);
            $displayRecProjImg = '<img src="/php'.$recProjImg.'" alt="'. $precProjAlt .'" class="projectDisplayImg">';
            $html = '';
            $html .= '<div class="recentProjectCont">';
            $html .= '<div class="recentProjectImg">';
            $html .= $displayRecProjImg;
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="recProjInfoCont">';
            $html .= '<div class="">';
            $html .= $precProjName;
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $recentProjData['html'][] = $html; //ADD TO THE ARRAY, INSTEAD OF OVERWRITING IT
            //$proj_arr[] = $data;
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
echo json_encode(['recentProjectData' => $recentProjData]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Why would the method where you loop through this via JS be better?

Comment: The method to loop through the JS would be better because it would give you more control over how to display the rows, since the code for each row is separated into an array, rather than in one long string.  Let's say, for some reason, you needed to only display two rows one one page, but all 5 in another... Or you need to re-order the rows because your boss said to.   You'd be able to control that via the JS loop.  Otherwise you'd need a more complex search/replace inside the string.

Comment: And if you want to get really technical, you are doing a form of RESTful API, so depending on how re-usable you want to make this, you're better off separating the data from the markup.  You should really only be returning an object of all the data.  That way, you can use the data on different pages/websites, but change the way it looks because you can create the markup independently for each use case.  By adding the markup, you are forcing whomever to use the layout and classes you've assigned.  Not a big deal if it's for you only, but defeats the point of RESTful APIs.

Comment: So by adding to the array for the JS method, how would I do that? I define each looped line is `$html`

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure I understand your question.  What do you mean by you "define each looped line is $html"?

Comment: You say to do this: `$recentProjData['html'][] = $html; //ADD TO THE ARRAY, INSTEAD OF OVERWRITING IT`. I don't get how I would do that when I am creating the html structure in this loop and each new line I put `$html`. OR are you saying to just define the loop rows. Then call the looped rows in the array, ie: `$displayRecProjImg` and then create the format while looping with the js?

Comment: My comment in that section states that you are adding the row to the array.  So basically, for every iteration of the foreach loop, you are storing one row of `<div class="recentProjectCont">` with all it's child elements into $html.  Then you are adding that one row to an array `$recentProjData['html']`.  You are not storing everything inside $html all at once, as you overwrite it with `$html = ''`... just one row at a time.  When you are done, you will get `$recentProjData = array( 'html' => array( 0 => '<div class="...', 1 => '<div class="...', ... ) );  Make sense?

Comment: You could even leave out the first array key if its easier, and just pass a single dimension array... but I was trying to make life easier for you.  I would suggest, if you are having difficulty understanding what's happening, to just use the first, easier method.  This means you wouldn't have to alter your JS, and everything would just work.